# Sum of column's values after filtering in another column excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have set filters on field 20 ,9 and 15

```
With dsWrksheet.Range("T1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="=*" & Id & "*"
    .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Controls Solutions"
    .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="India"
End With
```

After the filter is set I am calculating the sum of values in visible cells of column AB like this

```
Set myRange = dsWrksheet.Range("AB1:AB" & dsWrksheet.Range("AB" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
voucherValInd = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

The problem is arising when the cells are empty I am getting wrong values as sum.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal` is easier here. `109` means `SUM`, excluding hidden rows, as detailed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939). Plus, you can just use it on the entire column instead of finding the last row:

```
voucherValInd = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, dsWrksheet.Range("AB:AB"))
```